# Calling /me/home/ returns something that is not the same as the user's news feed

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed

Trying to build a news feed app.

I've seen /me/home/ used to get the user's news feed object, but from what I can tell, it returns something similar to the news feed but not exactly the same.
Some posts appear in /me/home/ that are not in the news feed, and a lot of posts that appear is the news feed are not in /me/home/.

Any way to get the same data with graph API?

Answer (score 0):

You can get everything from a user's stream by querying the FQL stream table.

`SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND type='newsfeed') AND is_hidden = 0`

Please read further about the stream at: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/

Comment: But graph API is much more convenient way of polling for data, and I get all the necessary information in a single object instead of querying different objects to fill my information.

Isn't there a way to get the same information from graphAPI?

Comment: What objects does that query miss?

Comment: It's just not the same as the news feed, I'm not entirely sure why, but it's just not the same filter. My guess is that there are different algorithms for stream and news feed...

Comment: Can you specify?  That FQL statement is direct from Facebook's documentation on how to get the newsfeed of an individual.  What feed items are you seeing that is missing? In my news feed, I get a 1:1 correlation between the FQL and the GUI.  Maybe my newsfeed isn't picking up all the types of items yours does.  What types of items is it missing?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was referring to Graph API and not FQL, I rather use Graph API because it's much more useful.

Comment: Please don't use a hammer as a saw, it's just not efficient